# Constructing bump like functions

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus

I was reading the paper [How to choose an activation function](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/874-how-to-choose-an-activation-function.pdf).

At page 3, the author is constructing a weird type of function that I am unable to visualize.

He says :

> We take an infinitely many times differentiable function $\psi$ which is equal to 1 on $[-2, 2]^s$ and 0 outside $[-\pi, \pi]^s$

I have trouble seeing how such a function exists. If the function takes the value 1 on $[-2,2]^s$ then on any small neighborhood around -2, the function should take the value 1 as well. In one dimension, I construct a taylor expansion around that point to prove this. So how does the function ever stop taking the value 1?

I would appreciate any example or someone to point out holes in my argument.

Comment: Taylor expansions don't necessarily have a positive radius of convergence. Consider $e^{-1/x^2}$. If you don't know what I'm talking about, try calculating it's derivatives at $x=0$. (Yes the function is undefined at 0, but the limit exists, so it can be extended to a continuous, indeed infinitely differentiable function at 0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classic example is $$f(x)=\begin {cases} 0&x \le 0\\e^{-\frac 1x}& x \gt 0\end {cases}$$
You should be able to verify that this is infinitely differentiable at all points.  The only question comes at zero, but all the derivatives are some polynomial in $\frac 1x$ times $e^{-\frac 1x}$  The exponential dominates over the polynomial and makes the limit of the derivative $0$ as $x \to 0$.

Functions that are equal to their Taylor series are analytic.  This one is not.  Once you understand this example you should be able to convince yourself that a function with the desired properties exists.  You need to patch together a few of these to start up from $0$, then stop at $1$, then start down from $1$, and finally stop at $0$.